# ADO.NET 2.0 under Mono examples?

Tags: .net, ado.net, mono, monodevelop

I've seen that ADO.NET 2.0 is compatible with Mono but I can't found any example of that in the web ?

Comment: I'm looking for an example under Mono of the use of ADO.NET 2.0 to generate classes from my database like ADO.NET make it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Pure ADO.NET doesn't generate classes. If you are looking for ORM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like Linq to SQL in mono then you should look at DbLinq (http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/). There is also ADO.NET Entity Framework in Visual Studio as ORM solution, but it's not supported in mono for now.

Comment: Ok pure ADO.NET examples I take if you have them.

Comment: Is DbLinq compatible withe Mono 2.4 and Monodevelopp 2.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://mono-project.com/MySQL) is ADO.NET example with MySQL database. If you are using MonoDevelop, then just add reference to MySQL connector dll. There are also some [examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html) about how to use the connector.

DbLinq should be compatible with mono 2.4 I would say, however it's still in preview release, so it's not ready for production use.

Comment: I don't think it's ADO.NET because we don't have the layer of persistance.

Comment: ADO.NET is not a layer of persistence nor ORM. From wiki page:  "ADO.NET is a set of computer software components that can be used by programmers to access data and data services. ...  It is commonly used by programmers to access and modify data stored in relational database systems ...". From MySQL .Net connector page: "...  It implements the required ADO.NET interfaces and integrates into ADO.NET aware tools. ... Connector/NET is a fully managed ADO.NET driver written in 100% pure C#."

Comment: As I said earlier, you are probably looking for Linq to SQL or Entity Framework implementations. Former is in mono world known as DbLinq (currently in preview release since mono 2.6) and latter is not implemented.

Comment: I think I use it unwittingly ;-) It's sure I want to employ Linq to SQL but unfortunately in Ubuntu synaptic has just the mono 2.4 version :-(